# Mounting a flash drive damaged home partition

Tags: filesystems, mount, fstab

I tried to mount flash drive file system in `/home/user/`.
The flash has bad partitions and file system isn't correct.

So i begin to iterate all fs-types. When it was

```
PARTUUID=23f59d6e-01 /home/user debugfs defaults 0 0,
```

executed

```
sudo mount -a
```

my home dir became clear.

The deletion this line from fstab and reexecuting

```
sudo mount -a
```

does not solve the problem. How can fix I it?

Comment: Does `sudo umount /home/user` help? It looks like you've just mounted another filesystem over your home directory.  Use another (empty) directory as the mount point for your experimentation with that flash drive.

Comment: prev comment is right. it was stupid mistake. thx

Answer (score 0):

You have mounted a new filesystem over the top of your home directory, hiding the contents of your home directory.

Simply un-mounting the mounted filesystem would reveal your files,

```
sudo umount /home/user
```

Then consider using an otherwise empty directory as mount point for you flash drive.